# How to make a correlation matrix from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, correlation

I'm trying to make a correlation matrix from a dataframe called `corr`, and it's composite for two columns of monthly data.

Here I show the dataframe:

```
corr1 = I['SUMA']
corr2 = I['H04_PEDRO_MARIN']
corr = pd.merge(corr1, corr2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
corr = corr.rename(columns={'SUMA':'Qentrada', 'H04_PEDRO_MARIN':'Qsalida' })
```

And here it's the datas:

```
 Qentrada    Qsalida
FECHA                        
2017-03   5.846582   8.547087
2017-04  16.185279  10.193128
2017-05  25.740979  15.925459
2017-06  39.012378  27.388582
2017-07  48.071437  34.819048
           ...        ...
2022-05  27.130179  20.408285
2022-06  45.317708  30.907428
2022-07  59.407663  46.606863
2022-08  59.302694  50.908523
2022-09  45.563384  34.496937

[67 rows x 2 columns]
```

I have tried to make the correlation matrix with the fuction .corr(), but it doesn't work, this is the result:

```
Qentrada   Qsalida
Qentrada  1.000000  0.680681
Qsalida   0.680681  1.000000
```

because  the final result I want to achieve is the correlation matrix between `Qentrada` and `Qsalida` along the time of the study for each year, i.e., one matrix by year, the four year that are in dataframe index.
And then, do the graphics.

This is an example that show how I want do the matrix:

```
                          Qsalida
                 2017-1   2017-2  2017-3  ...
         2017-1
         2017-2
Qentrada 2017-3
          ...
```

Here I put an example:

```
N = 100
index = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='B')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((N,3)), index=index)
df['month'] = df.index.month
result = df.groupby('month').corr()
print(result.head(9))
```

Result:

```
                0         1         2
month                                
1     0  1.000000 -0.000325 -0.208282
      1 -0.000325  1.000000 -0.236316
      2 -0.208282 -0.236316  1.000000
2     0  1.000000  0.056222 -0.010197
      1  0.056222  1.000000 -0.140247
      2 -0.010197 -0.140247  1.000000
3     0  1.000000 -0.064615 -0.111025
      1 -0.064615  1.000000 -0.100798
      2 -0.111025 -0.100798  1.000000
```

Thank u very much!

Comment: can you provide a small but complete example and the exact matching expected output?

Comment: Yes, I put it now, thank you very much